# Assign 0 and 1 based on values greater than in one line

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array with integers 1 through 10 and have to replace all integers less than 6 with 0 and all integers equal to or greater than 6 with 1.  Currently, I am doing this:

```
arry[arry < 6] = 0
arry[arry >= 6] = 1
```

I was wondering what would be a way to combine these two statements into one line of code, or any other solution for that matter.

Comment: This is a numpy array?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I should have mentioned that initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that `arry` is a numpy array (the smart indexing that you are using seems to indicate this). In that case you can simply do:

```
arry = (arry >= 6).astype(int)
```

where `astype(int)` will convert the array of booleans `arry >= 6` to an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1 if e >= 6 else 0 for e in arry]
```

for numpy array, `(arry >= 6)` gives an array of `True`/`False` which you can multiply by 1

```
(arry >= 6) * 1
```

or add 0

```
(arry >= 6) + 0
```

or cast to `int`

```
(a >= 6).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
array = [0 if num < 6 else 1 for num in arry]
```

Which is equivalent to the following loops:

```
temp = []
for num in arry:
    if num < 6:
        temp.append(0)
    else:
        temp.append(1)
arry = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(e >= 6) for e in arry]
```

This works because [`True` is defined to be the same value as `1` and `False` is defined to be the same value as `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10).

Comment: I would write: [1 if e >= 6 else 0 for e in arry]

Comment: This is a great solution! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda i: 0 if i<6 else 1, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map(function (n) {return n >= 6 ? 1 : 0})
```